# ActiveMQ Transport: tcp: Thread RUNNABLE state - too many threads hanging

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, message-queue, producer-consumer

Below ActiveMQ implementation is present in code. Sometimes, system stops working and become very slow. When I checked thread dump using JavaMelody - I have seen too many threads are on Runnable state for long time and is not being terminated.

**ActiveMQ version** - activemq-all-5.3.0.jar

Please refer below code :

**Broker :**

```
public class ActiveMQ extends HttpServlet {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -1234568008764323456;
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ActiveMQ.class.getName());
public Listener listener;

private String msgBrokerUrl = "tcp://localhost:61602";
public BrokerService broker = null;
public TransportConnector connector = null;

@Override
public void init() throws ServletException {

    try {
        broker = new BrokerService();
        broker.setPersistent(false);
        broker.setUseJmx(false);
        connector = broker.addConnector(msgBrokerUrl);
        broker.setUseShutdownHook(true);
        System.out.println("BROKER LOADED");
        broker.start();
        broker.deleteAllMessages();

        listener = new Listener();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

**Listener:**

```
public class Listener implements MessageListener {

private String msgQueueName = "jms/queue/MessageQueue";
public Session session;
public Destination adminQueue;

public static String id;

public ActiveMQConnection connection;
public MessageConsumer consumer = null;

public Listener() {
    try {

        ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(
                new URI("failover://(" + "tcp://localhost:61602" + "?wireFormat.cacheEnabled=false"
                        + "&wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration=0&wireFormat.tightEncodingEnabled=true)?maxReconnectDelay=1000"));

        connection = (ActiveMQConnection) connectionFactory.createConnection();
        connection.start();
        session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        adminQueue = session.createQueue(msgQueueName);
        id = new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()).toString();
        consumer = this.session.createConsumer(this.adminQueue, "ID='" + id + "'");
        consumer.setMessageListener(this);
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public void onMessage(Message message) {
    TextMessage msg = (TextMessage) message;
    try {
        String xmlMsg = msg.getText();
        // business logic
    } catch (JMSException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Producer :**

```
public class Producer {
private static String url = "tcp://localhost:61602";
private static String msgQueueName = "jms/queue/MessageQueue";

public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = null;
public Connection connection = null;
public Session session = null;
public Destination destination = null;

public Producer() {
    connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(url);
}

public void sendResponse(String xml, DataBean objDataBean) {
    sendToQueue(xml, msgQueueName, objDataBean);
}

private void sendToQueue(String xml, String msgQueueName, DataBean obj) {

    try {
        Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
        connection.start();
        Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        Destination destination = session.createQueue(msgQueueName);
        MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);
        TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage(xml);
        message.setJMSExpiration(1000);
        message.setStringProperty(obj.getMsgKey(), obj.getMsgValue());
        producer.send(message);

        xml = null;
        session.close();
        connection.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    for (int msg = 0; msg < 20; msg++) {
        DataBean obj = getData();
        new Producer().sendResponse(xml, obj);
        ;
    }
}
```

}

Hanging Threads Exception details :

*Type 1 :*

```
ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///127.0.0.1:41818
java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152)
java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpBufferedInputStream.fill(TcpBufferedInputStream.java:50)
org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpBufferedInputStream.read(TcpBufferedInputStream.java:58)
java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:387)
org.apache.activemq.openwire.OpenWireFormat.unmarshal(OpenWireFormat.java:272)
org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.readCommand(TcpTransport.java:210)
org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.doRun(TcpTransport.java:202)
org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.run(TcpTransport.java:185)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

*Type 2 :*

```
ActiveMQ Transport: tcp://localhost/127.0.0.1:61602
java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152)
java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpBufferedInputStream.fill(TcpBufferedInputStream.java:50)
org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpBufferedInputStream.read(TcpBufferedInputStream.java:58)
java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:387)
org.apache.activemq.openwire.OpenWireFormat.unmarshal(OpenWireFormat.java:272)
org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.readCommand(TcpTransport.java:210)
org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.doRun(TcpTransport.java:202)
org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.run(TcpTransport.java:185)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Please could you give some hints on this issue for further investigation.

**Edit:**
I read few posts on internet and concluded that I must update activemq jar file and implement timeout but when I started reading about timeout setting then I got confused whether I should set timeout in producer and consumer or failover or on message or broker service. Timeout at each component has different purpose then where I should implement timeout considering above code and exception.

Comment: Everything you have described is normal. If you have too many RUNNABLE this means you have too many threads for the CPU power you haves. Note: having thread waiting on `socketRead0` means the thread doesn't have anything to do (it's waiting for the other send to write something)

Comment: Why too many port number generated - I mean for each thread a unique port number is there.

Comment: tcp://localhost/127.0.0.1:61602 - This is again a concerned.

Comment: Each Socket has it's own port number as per the TCP/IP spec.

Comment: https://javaeesupportpatterns.blogspot.in/2011/04/javanetsocketinputstreamsocketread0.html

Answer (score 2):

Creating a connection is very expensive and when you close it, the port is retained for up to 3 minutes to ensure it is shutdown cleanly.

You want to create connections only when you really have to avoid performance problems.  I suggest you create the connection once, and keep that connection open unless you get an error. This can improve performance by 2 to 3 orders of magnitude.

This is a good performance tuning pattern which applies in many cases;

- only create and destroy expensive resources when you really have to.
- operations you perform many times should be kept to a minimum. i.e do repeatedly as little as possible.

Comment: As per the above code, listener connection is created only once and it's keep running where onMessage method getting called Continuously but Producer connection is being created for each run of loop from main method. Producer this is the problem where I will have to create connection only once..please advise.